# Track mousedown coordinates within set region over Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, event-handling, onmousedown

My page has a full screen flash object with a centered fixed content area (the rest background).

Without touching the flash source, I want to add "links" to set places within the content area to run script(s) (eg. ajax, event tracking) - similar to an image map.

**Needed:** - any page click compares the clicked x/y coordinates to a lookup table and if coordinates are within a "link" region, run a script - remember the coordinates are of the fixed content area within flash, not relative to the browser. *will the Flash animation and interactivity still work as normal?*

**Options tried:**

- set flash wmode=transparent and place a div containing links covering active area
  *This works in IE but Firefox disables the interactivity of the Flash file under the div layer*

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Internet explorer is the only browser that allows click events to be received by elements under transparent content, so an image map won't work.

I do not believe there is a way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Though, If you could edit the flash source you could capture the event there and then send the coordinates of the click to javascript through ExternalInterface.